# Create an Ingress resource in Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress

Im new to Ingress(k8s) and studying via documentation. Here is the 
[official documentation - Ingress Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#create-an-ingress-resource). Under ***Create and ingress resource***, I've already done steps 1-3 with no problem but I can't seem to do what step 4 asks. I have located the file inside the `ingress-nginx-controller` pod: `/etc/hosts`; but I can't seem to have any idea on how to edit it. I can't install vim-tiny or any other editing tools due to permission being denied. Sudo does not work. I just want to edit the `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular step (#4) should be done at your localhost, not inside ingress-controller pod. It`s just for mapping of hostname to IP addresses, so that you can verify if you can reach your application from outside exposed by Ingress resource.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the answer. I just recently found about this also. It was just kind of confusing when following the steps. I think they should elaborate more on this step since many beginners like me might also get confused

Answer (score 0):

that is ip address or step is to setup DNS A record which expose your application to outside netwrok kubernetes cluster.

```
ingress > service > POD
```